# org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws

i have an EAR containing a web module exposing SOAP services developed with jaxws.
Everything works fine but when i have an error, i throw typically new BusinessFault(...).
Then i'm getting the below error.
The EAR is deployed on WLS 12.1 with glassfish.jaxws.rt_2.0.0.0_2-2-5.jar.
As the error message is completely useless.

I'll provide more details if necessary.

Thanks in advance

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextWrapper.(JAXBContextWrapper.java:78)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextFactory.newContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:115)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:146)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.create(JAXBMessage.java:161)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAP11Fault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:423)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:200)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:188)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.createResponse(TieHandler.java:272)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.serializeResponse(TieHandler.java:338)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.serializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:200)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.serializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:264)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:106)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:892)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:841)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:804)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:706)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:430)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:640)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:265)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:163)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:171)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:708)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
        at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:103)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:311)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:336)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:99)
        at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:235)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3284)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
03-Apr-2014 12:16:00 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit handle
SEVERE: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextWrapper.(JAXBContextWrapper.java:78)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.db.toplink.JAXBContextFactory.newContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:115)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.BindingContextFactory.create(BindingContextFactory.java:146)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.create(JAXBMessage.java:161)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAP11Fault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:423)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:200)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createSOAPFaultMessage(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:188)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:436)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:640)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:265)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:163)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:171)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:708)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
        at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:103)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:311)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:336)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:99)
        at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:235)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3284)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2089)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

Comment: Are you saying that `glassfish.jaxws.rt_2.0.0.0_2-2-5.jar` is included in your `ear`?  If so why have you packaged things this way?

Comment: Thanks Blaise for replying.
glassfish.jaxws.rt_2.0.0.0_2-2-5.jar is in WLS_HOME/modules/, it is not in my ear.